# Multitape Turing Machine to shorten one's name

Tags: turing-machines

I am trying to formulate a multi-tape Turing Machine which converts one's name in the form of "(Firstname with the first letter in caps)(space)(Lastname with the first letter in caps)" to "(First letter of Lastname in caps). (space)(Firstname with the first letter in caps)".

For example, "Jayajit Banerjee" will be converted to "B. Jayajit".

I cannot understand how to approach and solve this problem. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a multi-tape TM for that.

When you see a "space", replace it with a ".". From this point on, the "state" of the TM will be the current letter it sees. Then, it will read the next letter and replace it with the current one. continue doing this until the end of the string.

Comment: But does this not traverse through the entire string? I'm asking this as the question asks us to use only the first letter of the last name

Comment: You need to add a letter between the first name and the last name, so you will anyways need to shift the last name one cell forward - to make place for that added letter.

Comment: You mean "add a space", right? Just to clarify, the output should not have anything after the first name.